# How to don't allow an iframe to download css, js and image files?

Tags: html, file, iframe

I need an iframe but I don't need it to load it's referencing files like css, js and images. How I might do it?

Comment: Don't include them at all. There is no other way.

Comment: I need the iframe in order to post in crossdomain..

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't.

The long answer is to get a version of the HTML document you plan to load but without all the references you don't want and load that instead.

(You could generate such a document programatically, using your programming language of choice and a DOM parser).

Comment: @Totty He's not suggesting you don't use an IFRAME. He's saying that you cannot style the content of an IFRAME once you've fetched it, so your only option is to intercept it, transform it, then release it to the IFRAME.

Comment: So how exactly I can do it?